# How can I set the horizontal scroll bar to asp chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-charts

I am using the following code to display ASP.NET chart control on my page and it is working fine. My problem is, I need to set horizontal scroll bar on x-axis,

```
protected void BindDataToChart2()
{
    Chart1.DataSource = local_ds.Tables[3];
    Chart1.Legends.Add("legend1").Title = "LocalIP Details";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Login Date";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "No. of Clients";
    Chart1.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "LoginDate";
    Chart1.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "clients";
    Chart1.DataBind();
}
```

and this is ASP.NET chart control.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "set horizontal scroll bar"?  Can you show an example of a site which demonstrates the behavior you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be achieved by simply putting the Chart to a Panel and setting the Panel's `ScrollBars` Property to "Horizontal"

```
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
       <asp:Chart 
           ....
       </asp:Chart>
   </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Hi, It seems to be that, the problem is cleared but here whole chart is scrolling so can't able to see the Y-axis values, what you have done for that?

Comment: The Chart control generates the picture of the chart in server-side and this picture is displayed in an img tag in the generated html. So I don't think that it is even possible to scroll only the part of that.

Comment: But an alternative solution could be that in the aspx markup: <asp:Chart ...> <Series> <asp:Series ... IsValueShownAsLabel="true" ... The y values are displayed (I don't know what kind of diagram it is so sorry if it doesn't good for you.

Comment: ya, ok i done this temporary, and will see later if there is any better idea, thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
  chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;